# TextBox and Button JS Onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textbox. I wanted to use a JS onclick to append the input in the textbox to the "btnGO" button as below but it's not working:

```js
document.getElementById('btnGo').onclick = function() {
  var search = document.getElementById('dlrNum').value;
  window.location.url = "http://consumerlending/app/indirect/dealerComments.aspx?dlrNum=" + search;
}
```

```html
<input id="dlrNum" type="text" name="dlrNum" autocompletetype="disabled" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
<input id="btnGo" type="submit" value="GO" name="GO" runat="server">
```

What could I be missing?

Comment: what's not working ? is it  navigating to the wrong link ?

Comment: The link isn't even loading

Comment: a) You should wrap this code to the `onload` listener; b) `window.location.assign(URL)`

Comment: What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: Where are you putting this javascript? If it is in the head, you'll need to wrap it so that it waits for the elements to load before trying to bind events to them. Otherwise, it can go at the end of the `<body>` section.

Comment: It's at the end of the body section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had several problems there:
1. Your `<input>` elements are probably part of a `form`, so when you click on the submit button - the form will submit, unless you prevent it.
2. You need to use `window.location.href` (and not `.url`).

Here is the fix to your code:

```
document.getElementById('btnGo').onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var search = document.getElementById('dlrNum').value;
    window.location.href = "http://consumerlending/app/indirect/dealerComments.aspx?dlrNum=" + search;
}
```

> Note the `e` element inside the `function(e)` - it's there so we can use the event object to prevent the default behavior of the form submission.

Answer (score 1):

Update `window.location.url` to `window.location`:

```
window.location = "http://consumerlending/app/indirect/dealerComments.aspx?dlrNum=" + search;
```